# Is it possible to remotely cancel a scheduled shutdown when /run/nologin exists?

Tags: ssh, shutdown

Consider this scenario:

1. User `ssh` into a system and does whatever he/she wants.
2. Then schedules a `shutdown` using:

   ```
   sudo shutdown -h +1
   ```
3. Finally closes the ssh session

Now `/run/nologin` has been created and no one can login anymore, but something comes up and we want to `ssh` back to the system before it goes down.

Is it possible to remotely cancel the scheduled shutdown when we are not permitted to login any more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beside of using "root" account to make a new `ssh` connection, we can actually use PAM to allow specific user or groups logging in.

PAM configurations of `sshd` are located at: `/etc/pam.d/sshd` which are in responsible of what you are looking for.

By editing this file and using `pam_succeed_if.so` we can allow specific user or group to login even when `/run/nologin` exists on machine.

> pam_succeed_if.so is designed to succeed or fail authentication based on characteristics of the account belonging to the user being authenticated or values of
>          other PAM items. One use is to select whether to load other modules based on this test.

So we use it to detect whatever we should load `pam_nologin.so` module or not based on your username or user-group.

Open the file using your favorite text editor:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

And find these lines:

```
# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so
```

Add this line between them:

```
account  [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user notingroup sudo
```

So now the lines should look like this:

```
# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account  [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user notingroup sudo
account  required     pam_nologin.so
```

Now users who are in `sudo` group can login even when `/run/nologin` exists.

And to allow a specific user:

```
account [default=2 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet user != username
```

For more flexible conditions checkout:

```
man pam_succeed_if
```

Answer (score 3):

If `root` can remotely login to the system, `nologin` is ignored.  However, most sane admins will not permit `root` to directly login remotely, in favor of an authorized user logging in and using `sudo`.  If the latter is not the case, however, `root` can log in and abort the shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

The `nologin` is ignored for user root. So you could use SSH to connect as root, but you probably have a distribution that doesn't allow root logins by default. You can create a SSH key and place it in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then you can login with that key as root.